# Javascript bookmarklet outputting 'true' in Firefox instead of performing script

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

We are running a quick javascript function to fill out and save a form to quickly move forward in a workflow (for testing purposes). It's running fine in all browsers except for Firefox - and only on a couple people's machines.

```
javascript:!function(){$("#ruleDetailForm\\.authorizingStatutes").val("Test")}();
```

There is more to the script, but the above example results in the same issue. Both copying it into the URL bar or adding it as a bookmarklet results in a blank white page displaying 'true' instead of copying "Test" into the relevant field.

The same users have no issues using other browsers, and other people have had success with it working in Firefox. Firebug doesn't show anything useful, and they are on the most up-to-date version of Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping in in void

```
javascript:void(function(){$("#ruleDetailForm\\.authorizingStatutes").val("Test")}());
```

Comment: Note that you also removed the exclamation mark at the beginning of the script, which might have had something to do with the issue. Also, I know you're better than a "Try this" answer... ;)

Comment: I removed the exclamation mark, but also left out 'void' - I simply wrapped everything in parens and it is now working for the referenced users in Firefox. Thanks for starting me down the right path!